# Error while creating react app using "create-react-app my-app"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I have started working on react, and I am getting an error while creating react app using `create-react-app my-app` command
I have successfully installed create-react- app using `npm install -g create-react-app` command
While creating an app I got an error like below:

[image]

I have tried many solutions like `npm cache clean --force` command
I have also tried to reinstall nodejs and npm

Can anyone know what is the issue? and how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you take a look at the log?

Comment: yes, it shows same error as shown in screenshot stated `error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...mocha":"*"},"_hasShri'`

Answer (score 0):

My friend had the same problem. Exactly at the date you posted, he first encountered the same issue. But, he was running `npm install` rather than the creation of a react-app.

His setup is a Ubuntu VM in Windows. Within Windows, the `npm install` was working fine, but not within Ubuntu. With every try to solve the issue, we faced SSL errors in Ubuntu. Maybe check the given log output file and search for the first error there.

The fix was installing latest updated in his Windows. Apparently, they somehow broke his ethernet adapter driver in Windows. And forwarding of SSL certificate information was broken with that update.

Thus, I recommend to check for (Windows) updates for your ethernet adapter.